# Origin of the following phrase: Ambulatoria enim est voluntas hominum usque ad vitae supremum exitum

Tags: passage-request, origin

I can't find where this text comes from:

> Ambulatoria enim est voluntas hominum usque ad vitae supremum exitum.

I can't find the author on the internet. What is the source of this phrase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase is actually slightly different:

> ambulatoria enim est voluntas **defuncti** usque ad vitae supremum exitum.

This means:

> For the will of a dead man is changeable until his final departure from life.

This comes from the [*Digest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_(Roman_law)) (or *Pandects*):

> The Digest, also known as the Pandects (Latin: Digesta seu Pandectae, adapted from Ancient Greek πανδέκτης pandektes, "all-containing"), is a name given to a compendium or digest of Roman law compiled by order of the Eastern Roman (Byzantine) emperor Justinian I in the 6th century (AD 530-533). It spans 50 volumes, and represented a reduction and codification of all Roman laws up to that time.

The full passage is [Dig. 34.4.4.](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/justinian/digest34.shtml):

> Quod si iterum in amicitiam redierunt et paenituit testatorem prioris offensae, legatum vel fideicommissum relictum redintegratur: ambulatoria enim est voluntas defuncti usque ad vitae supremum exitum.

This particular quote is compiled from the writing of [Ulpian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulpian) (c. 170-223). I am not sure if this particular quote is extant beyond the transmission from the *Digest*.

This appears to have gained some popularity as a legal maxim regarding will-writing: a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ambulatoria+enim+est+voluntas+defuncti%22) reveals several hundred results from old legal books. The basic idea is that a will can be changed as long as the person in question is alive.